# Sharing an IPython slideshow on Dropbox

Tags: python, ipython, slideshow, dropbox

I copied my ipynb file to Dropbox, clicked on share, got a link to the file that looks something like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/foo/bar.ipynb?dl=0

To view it from the browser, I just need to replace `dl=0` with `raw=1`.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/foo/bar.ipynb?raw=1

Then I visited [IPython Slides Viewer](https://slideviewer.herokuapp.com/) and pasted this raw url.

I get a 400: Bad Request error.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on both links... have you moved the file or something?

Comment: @PaulGowder Pretty sure those were just example links - I doubt OP could get `foo` in the dropbox random link generator!

Comment: You may want to try put it on Github and it become viewable on [NBviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org) right away.

Comment: Thanks...nbviewer works!

Comment: If you want help with the original issue, update your post with an actual link that shows the issue, as a raw=1 link worked in IPython Slides Viewer for me.